# I want to calculate the average sum of some floats. But I got strange results

Tags: python, user-input, precision, floating-accuracy

So i ask the user for some numerical inputs with a loop.
After that the inputs are being processed the mathematical result is slightly different than the actual math done with a calculator.
Does it take the 0 break value as input and somehow messes up my average ?

```
values = []
while True:
  m = float(input("Number of shares?, 0 for Exit: "))
  n = float(input("Total price of purchase?, 0 for Exit:"))
  if m == 0:
      break
  if n == 0:
      break
  values.append(m)
  sum = n/m

print(sum)
```

Answer (score -1):

### First things first:

I assume, you want to save the prize of a transaction (shares * price), put this number in the array **values** and then you want to calculate the average number from your array **values**. Your code doesn't do that.

```py
sum = n/m # calculates **only** n / m and saves it **only** in the variable sum.
# You overwrite sum every loop.
```

Try this:

```py
values = []
while True:
  m = float(input("Number of shares?, 0 for Exit: ")) # Caution! It's not a good idea to use a float here!
  n = float(input("Total price of purchase?, 0 for Exit:")) # Caution! It's not a good idea to use a float here!
  if m == 0:
      break
  if n == 0:
      break
  values.append(n * m) # append the price of the transaction into values

print( sum(values) / len(values) ) # gives you the average prize per transaction
```

Caution! Exmample: Give m = 1.1 and n = 1.1 and only one transaction. Output is 1.2100000000000002!

Why?

### Short Answer:

Avoid using floats. Instead use doubles. And if you are handling currencies never ever use floats/doubles. In python you could use [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html), if you need more precision.

### Long Answer:

You are trying to calculate with floats.
Most modern programming language use the standard [IEEE_754-1985](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985) to store floats. In IEEE-754, some numbers couldn't be exact represented as an float. Because of it's binary Structure. As an example the number *0.1*.

1.0 as a float is:

```
0 01111111 00000000000000000000000
```

The first bit stands for the sign. If it is *zero* the number is a positiv number. If it is *one*, it is negative.

-1.0:

```
1 01111111 00000000000000000000000
```

The 8 bits after the sign-bit is the *exponent*.
The 23 bits after the exponent bits are the mantissa.

What happens if we have a *one* in the most significant bit in the mantissa?

```
0 01111111 10000000000000000000000
```

We have now a 1.0 + 2^-1. That is 1.5.

And what is:

```
0 01111111 01000000000000000000000
```

We have now a 1.0 + 2^-2. That is 1.25.

1.1 is:

```
0 01111111 00011001100110011001101
```

1.0 + 2^-4 + 2^-5 + 2^-8 + 2^-9 + 2^-12 + 2^-13 + 2^-16 + 2^-17 +2^-20 + 2^-21 + 2^-23

That's: 1.10000002384185791015625
The Single precision gives you approximately 1.10000000.

You could use Double precision. A double contains 64 bits. 1 for the sign, 11 for the exponent and 52 bit for the mantissa. But 0.1 is still only an approximately number and not exact 0.1.

### Solution

```py
from decimal import Decimal

values = []
while True:
  m = Decimal(input("Number of shares?, 0 for Exit: "))
  n = Decimal(input("Total price of purchase?, 0 for Exit:"))
  if m == 0:
      break
  if n == 0:
      break
  values.append(n * m)

average = sum(values) / len(values) 
print(average)
```

Comment: It seems that double digits instead of floats are not the issue. Its because i was writing multiple numerical inputs but the average calculation was being done only for the last 2 inputs entered. The code i wrote does not store all of the inputs from the user and only takes into consideration the last 2 .

Comment: In fact your code stores all of the inputs. But you don't use it. You are calculating n / m and put it in **sum**. After your loop is ending: you are printing the last **sum**.